# Firebase with react .on listener not working

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase and for some reason this was just working, but now it is not. I have an `onChange` event on an input which is working just fine, but for some reason the firebase `.on()` method is not working for me.

here is what I have:

```
updateUsername(event) {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    });

    const usernameRef = fire.database().ref('usernames');
    if (event.target.value) {
      usernameRef.child(event.target.value).on('value', snap => {
        console.log(snap.val()); // returns nothing
        if (snap.val() != null) {
          this.setState({
            disabled: true
          });
        } else if (snap.val() == null) {
          this.setState({
            disabled: false
          });
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why it was working earlier, but I needed to change the `.read` rules inside the firebase console of my project to `true`

old rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

new rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```